# ag-grid unit testing in angular2- fixture.nativeElement.query is not a function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

I wrote a test case by using Karma/Jasmine for ag-grid in angular. In my test case just checking the ag-grid headers and getting error like "fixture.nativeElement.query is not a function" but i am not confident enough whether this is a right approach or not which i have written. If any one having idea please help me.

This is my test case

```js
it('to test the column headers',()=>{
    fixture.nativeElement.query(By.css(".ag-fresh"))
    .map(function (header){
      return header.getText()
    }).then(function(headers){
      expect(headers).toEqual(['color','qty','price']);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `query()` on `fixture.debugElement`. And also I don't think you need to `map` the result here.

`fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".ag-fresh")).nativeElement` should do it for you.

Comment: Is their any source links available for ag-grid unit testing by using Jasmine/Karma.

Answer (score 0):

Following approches can be taken to get element in Unit Testing

In general, it's recommended to use `debugElement` for interacting with the DOM in Angular tests, as it provides a higher level of abstraction that is specifically designed for testing Angular components.

- querySelector -> is a native DOM method
- debugElement -> is an object provided by Angular's TestBed that represents a wrapper around a DOM element.

```
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(<Component>)
```

```
// using querySelector
 const element = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement
 const domElem = element.querySelector(<CSS Selector>)
```

```
// using debugElement
 let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(<CSS Selector>)) as DebugElement
 const domElem = de.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
```